# Add yes or no button to messagebox c#

Tags: c#

I have this code for a messagebox:

```
private void ControlComp_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            if (changed == true)
            {
                string message = "Do you want to exit without saving?";
                string caption = "exit";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
                DialogResult result;

                result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon);

                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

What i need to do is, i check if the changed value is true  only if it's true it displays a popup message, with a yes or no button, if yes is clicked i quit the entire form else i stay in the form.

If changed value is false then again i close it.
But this code doesn't work.

Comment: Funny question title, considering you already do have a yes and no button on the message box. And *this code doesn't work* is not really helping either.

Comment: why these much downvotes that too without putting the reason??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel the closing of the form, in your else statement you need `e.Cancel = true`;

See below sample code :-

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i will accept it in a few min